# Get HTML <td> tag values to PHP variable or JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please See the following coding

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                               <th>Consignee Name</th>
                               <th>Reference Code</th>
                               <th>Consignee Number</th>
                               <th>Consignee Email</th>
                               <th>Consignee Address</th>
                               <th>COD</th>
                               <th>Pieces</th>
                               <th>Wieght</th>
                               <th>City</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>


                            <tbody>
                                <?
                                    foreach($sheet_data as $sheet){
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?=$sheet['C']?></td>
                                        <td><?=$sheet['D']?></td>
                                        <td><?=$sheet['E']?></td>
                                        <td><?=$sheet['F']?></td>
                                        <td><?=$sheet['G']?></td>
                                        <td><?=$sheet['H']?></td>
                                        <td><?=$sheet['I']?></td>
                                        <td><?=$sheet['J']?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="form-control select2" name="city_id">
                                                <?php
                                                    foreach ($cities as $city) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?=$city['ref_id']?>" <?
                                                    if($sheet['L']==$city['name'])
                                                    echo 'selected';
                                                    ?>><?=$city['name']?></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?
                                    }
                                    ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

I want to Get the data of every  to an array.
I dont know how to do that.
Its a large data like 100+ rows.
Also there is a select input in td i want to get the value of that to

Array made should be JavaScript so that i can post the value by ajax to a controller(PHP)

Comment: since you want to pass select,input and so on why you dont submit a form to controller ?

Comment: oh, you mean that add a <form> tag and then submit a form
but then that would require name attributes and same name attributes will not be submitted

Comment: <td><input name='sheetc' value="<?=$sheet['C']?>"/></td>
now imagine 100+ <tr>

Comment: <input name='sheetc[]'  like this will  submit all of them in array

Comment: wait let me check and get back to you thats a very good approach thou

Comment: I did your approach and got it, pasting the code in the comments, thanks @iv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this easily using Javascript or jQuery. I am following the jQuery approach. See below example.

```js
 // Perform some action on button click
jQuery('#getValues').click(function(){
//We will iterate over all rows in inside tbody of table with id myTable 
  jQuery('#myTable tbody tr').each(function(index, tr) {
         var lines =jQuery('td', tr).map(function(index, td) {
          return jQuery(td).text();
// This will save all date in lines array
    });
  
// Now test lines array by doing a console.log()
      console.log(lines[0] + ' ' + lines[1] + ' '  + lines[2] + ' '  + lines[3] );
    })
    // Now you have all values in lines array. You can send this complete array via ajax to server.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th> Col1 </th>
      <th> Col2 </th>
      <th> Col3 </th>
      <th> Col4 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
  <td> Value 11 </td>
  <td> Value 12 </td>
  <td> Value 13</td>
  <td> Value 14 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td> Value 21 </td>
  <td> Value 22 </td>
  <td> Value 23</td>
  <td> Value 24 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> Value 31 </td>
  <td> Value 32 </td>
  <td> Value 33</td>
  <td> Value 34 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> Value 41 </td>
  <td> Value 42 </td>
  <td> Value 43</td>
  <td> Value 44 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

<button id="getValues"> Get all values </button>
```

All necessary comments are added to the above code.  You can modify the example as per your needs.

Comment: yes this code does provide what i want, but what about the select element,
it would just get the td.html() value, and there is a select element in a td

Comment: You can get selected value of a drop-down or select element by using `jQuery("option:selected").val() `

Comment: You will need to iterate over `td` text values and check for if td contains `<select>` than get selected value using `jQuery("option:selected").val()`

Comment: I implemented your code and works perfectly fine, but due to some stupid server issue I've to go to the commented answer, your answer is selected also as both the solutions works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                               <th>Consignee Name</th>
                               <th>Reference Code</th>
                               <th>Consignee Number</th>
                               <th>Consignee Email</th>
                               <th>Consignee Address</th>
                               <th>COD</th>
                               <th>Pieces</th>
                               <th>Wieght</th>
                               <th>City</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>


                            <tbody>
                                <form action="<?=base_url()?>client/save_excel_date" method="POST">
                                <?
                                $count=1;
                                    foreach($sheet_data as $sheet){
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input class="form-control" name="sheetc[a<?=$count?>]" value="<?=$sheet['C']?>"></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control" name="sheetd[a<?=$count?>]" value="<?=$sheet['D']?>"></td> 
                                        <td><input class="form-control" name="sheete[a<?=$count?>]" value="<?=$sheet['E']?>"></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control" name="sheetf[a<?=$count?>]" value="<?=$sheet['F']?>"></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control" name="sheetg[a<?=$count?>]" value="<?=$sheet['G']?>"></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control" name="sheeth[a<?=$count?>]" value="<?=$sheet['H']?>"></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control" name="sheeti[a<?=$count?>]" value="<?=$sheet['I']?>"></td>
                                        <td><input class="form-control" name="sheetj[a<?=$count?>]" value="<?=$sheet['J']?>"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="form-control select2" name="city_id[a<?=$count?>]">
                                                <?php
                                                    foreach ($cities as $city) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?=$city['ref_id']?>" <?
                                                    if($sheet['L']==$city['name'])
                                                    echo 'selected';
                                                    ?>><?=$city['name']?></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?
                                    $count++;
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                                    </form>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

And in the controller

```
$data   =   $this->input->post();
    $consignee_name     =   $data['sheetc'];
    $consignee_ref     =   $data['sheetd'];
    $consignee_number     =   $data['sheete'];
    $consignee_email     =   $data['sheetf'];
    $consignee_address     =   $data['sheetg'];
    $cod     =   $data['sheeth'];
    $pcs     =   $data['sheeti'];
    $weight     =   $data['sheetj'];
    $city_id     =   $data['city_id'];


    $arrays     =   array_merge_recursive($consignee_name,$consignee_ref,$consignee_number,$consignee_email,$consignee_address,$cod,$pcs,$weight,$city_id);
    print("<pre>".print_r($arrays,true)."</pre>");die;
```